# Return average of all cells in column F where corresponding cell in column c contains text "1of1"

Tags: excel-formula

We have a really old dataset of mail campaigns, with various bits of stats I want to pull some trends from.
I basically want an average of the numbers that correspond to name types. Not sure if I need to write a complex indirect function, but Im not particularly Excel literate
Any questions, by all means ask
thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily if you can add a new (temporary) column to your table (in this example called X).
In the fields of column X you put a formula that displays the value of F if C contains the text.
In X1 this would look like this:

```
=IF(C1="1of1";F1;"")
```

Since those formulars are language dependent you might have to look for the corresponding function to "IF". After setting the formula up in row 1 you can "drag" it down into all rows.

Now you can use the normal average formula over the column X.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"1of1",F:F)/COUNTIF(C:C,"1of1")
```

anywhere but in ColumnC or ColumnF.